# How can I find the definition of the method load_weights of the class keras.models?

Tags: github, keras, methods

I'm trying to find the definition of the method `load_weights` of class `keras.models`. Where can I find it? In Pytorch it's very easy because each entry in Pytorch docs links to the corresponding source code. In Keras this doesn't happen, and I couldn't find the source code for this method on Github. I'm looking for an answer which explains how to find such information, rather than just a link to the source code. This way, I won't have to ask a new question each time I need to look for the source code of a `keras` method.

Comment: This is really not meant to be snarky but since you asked: I've entered `git load_weights keras.models` in Google which shows me that `tf.keras.models` is being imported in `keras/keras/models.py` via the [engine](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py). From the TF doc for tf.keras.models, I then clicked the Github page link to see the [code for load_weights](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L2109). Note that this is different for older Keras versions.

Comment: @runDOSrun I didn't know that I should search the source under `tf.keras` instead than in the `keras` repository. Thanks

Comment: Keras has been discontinued in favor of `tf.keras` which is why the newest standalone version is just a giant redirect to `tf.keras`. If you go to earlier versions in Git, you will find `load_weights` where you've originally been looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keras Standalone](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) has been discontinued in favor of `tf.keras` which is why the newest standalone version (2.4.0) is just a giant redirect to `tf.keras`. This is why you will find `Model.load_weights` in the [tensorflow repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L2109).

If you go to earlier versions of Keras (<2.2.5), you will find `load_weights` where you've originally been looking for it, namely in Keras itself, in [model.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c45f48eaeab2a9c9a809488950f07d83abe18411/keras/models.py#L691).